# How to get class of last element by using name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually i have a form. And a button near it. So each time the button is pressed, a new form will append dynamically.

So here i need the last form input element's class name.

I have used the following,

```
 $('name="username[]").length:last
```

Am getting the element here(whole html for that element).

How to get its class name???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.length` will return number of matched elements, but if you want to get the **[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector)** element whose `name=username[]` then you should use selector `$('[name="username[]"]:last')` like,

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('[name="username[]"]:last').attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username[]" class="first" /> <br/>
<input type="text" name="username[]" class="second" /> <br/>
<input type="text" name="username[]" class="third" /> <br/>
<input type="text" name="username[]" class="forth" /> <br/>
<input type="text" name="username[]" class="last fifth" /> <br/>
```

Comment: Yea, I have done this many times. But here I forgot to remove `length`. 
Am trying like `('[name="username[]"].length:last').attr('class'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`last()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJs7vR04rUAhVHPo8KHflEBjYQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Flast%2F&usg=AFQjCNFzajoxFcjnOZMpsGR0tRX6jf-uWA)  and [`attr()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3_dvf04rUAhWHvY8KHYjvBtoQFggmMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fattr%2F&usg=AFQjCNE1qhpJI2G8J0vSJXrZ_Vf8dTKrTg) of jquery function

```
   $('[name="username[]"]').last().attr('class')
```

Working snippet

```js
console.log($('[name="username[]"]').last().attr('class'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]">username[]</p>
<p name="username[]" class="lastelemnet">username[]</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget the mismatched quotes